# unable to copy xlsx file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to copy a folder from one location to another but it fails when xlsx is present in the folder.

```
copy_tree("D:\\test\\files", "E:\\test")
```

The error is got,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 10, in <module>
    shutil.copy2("D:/test/files/first.xlsx", "E:/test/1.xlsx")
  File "C:\Python\lib\shutil.py", line 263, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Python\lib\shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E:/test/1.xlsx'
```

I tried to copy the single file alone instead of copying the folder. Still the same result.

And i tried to open a xlsx file in wb mode & it also throws the same error (Using the below code).

```
with open(dst_file, 'wb') as dest:
```

I tried giving full permission to the folder and files still no luck.

I am using windows 10

Comment: Is your file opened in MS Excel or in any software when you are trying to copy it? If so please close the file first and then try copy again.

Comment: The traceback in your question does not match the code you say you're using. The code shows a call to `copy_tree()` but in the traceback `shutil.copy2()` is shown as the top of the call chain.

Comment: @martineau Sorry wrong error trace the error trace for copy2. But got the same error in copy_tree

Comment: @SalmanAhmed Checked that no luck

Comment: Knowing exactly what function you're calling matters because some have optional arguments that may be helpful. For example a copy utility might not allow overwriting existing files unless doing so is expressly allowed via some keyword argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
     import os
     #create a file at the location that you want to copy. 
     f1=open("file1",'a')

     #the file with content
     f2=open("file2",'r')

     f1.write(f2.read())


     f1.seek(0)
     f2.seek(0)

     if os.path.exists("f2 path "):
        os.remove("file2 path")
```

#the file at older location will be deleted.

Comment: The OP tried `open(dst_file, 'wb')` which have the same error - please reread the question.